# Flagging answers as "not an answer"

Tags: discussion

We seem to be getting quite a few answers flagged as "not an answer". Whilst some certainly were not answers, others seem to be flagged simply because they didn't fully answer the question, or were a bad answer.

If we look at the pop-up box for flagging we see this:

[image: Flagging dialog]

Notice that the flag needs that the answer does not **attempt** to answer the question. Examples could be:

- Gibberish
- Someone saying they have the *same problem* as in the question
- The original poster (OP) *clarifying the question* in an answer rather than editing the original question
- Asking a *new question* as an answer
- Someone seeking *clarification of the question* (this should be done as a comment on the question)
- Someone *commenting on one of the other answers*

---

However these are not suitable for flagging as "not an answer":

- Bad answers
- Wrong answers
- Incomplete answers

---

In these cases you, the user of this site, have options available to you. You can:

- Add a comment explaining why you think the answer is wrong
- Vote the answer down (preferably commenting why you are doing this, so that a third party will understand why an answer got down votes)
- Post a better answer yourself

Comment: Is it only me or I want downvotes to be free after like 1.5k rep. The number of bad anwsers (including mine) are quite high. There is no real "close answer" so yeah...